# How to block internet if one of gateways is down

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ip, routing

I have router with VPN client. Sometimes something goes wrong and connecton to VPN is down. I'd like to restrict clients from connection to the internet directly (without VPN) in this case.

Is it possibe to block traffic via 192.168.10.1 if 146.70.131.XX is down?

- 192.168.10.1 -- gateway to the internet
- 146.70.131.XX -- vpn

| Destination | Gateway | Genmask | Flags | MSS Window | irtt | Iface |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | 192.168.0.1 | 0.0.0.0 | UG | 0 0 | 0 | ppp5 |
| default | 192.168.10.1 | 0.0.0.0 | UG | 0 0 | 0 | vlan2 |
| 127.0.0.0 | * | 255.0.0.0 | U | 0 0 | 0 | lo |
| 146.70.131.XX | 192.168.10.1 | 255.255.255.255 | UGH | 0 0 | 0 | vlan2 |
| 192.168.10.0 | * | 255.255.255.0 | U | 0 0 | 0 | vlan2 |
| 192.168.10.1 | * | 255.255.255.255 | UH | 0 0 | 0 | vlan2 |
| 192.168.50.0 | * | 255.255.255.0 | U | 0 0 | 0 | br0 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should use both text and an image for text, just format the text, so it can be read easily

Comment: @Ramhound fixed